# IMAP error when accessing gmail from command line

Tags: python, email, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am working on writing a simple script to read unread mail from gmail through a python script. I have the following script, but when I run the python script, I get the IMAP error marked below. Any assistance in this issue is appreciated.

I have IMAP enabled in my gmail settings. Is there any other configuration that I need to take care of, to get this working?

```
import imaplib
obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com','993')
obj.login('username','password')
obj.select()
obj.search(None,'Unseen')
```

where, `username` is my gmail username, and `password` is the password for my gmail account.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    obj.login('ashwin.tumma23@gmail.com',password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 519, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.error: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser:    
https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
```

Comment: There are some suggestions at [that URL](https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754) for diagnosing the problem. Have you looked at that list? Have you successfully accessed GMail via IMAP using an existing IMAP client (mutt/Apple Mail/Thunderbird/whatever)?

Comment: Did you check https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 ? Do you have two factor auth enabled?

Comment: No, I don't have two factor auth enabled

Answer (score 2):

visibleman's answer is correct. As an alternative though you may wish to switch your script to using the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) instead of IMAP. Gmail API uses OAuth 2.0 for authentication which is much more secure. Gmail API is also a much easier protocol to work with than IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I am not sure which step finally solved it but here is what I did:

- Go to settings page, enable IMAP and click save changes
- Log out and back in via web interface
- enable 'less secure'  at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
- Log in via imaplib (create new obj first)

It seems that after this, you can again disable 'less secure' and it still works.